# database design for houses selling website in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I am designing a database for a website of selling houses and lands. I have an issue that is the house may be in one or many lands, and the land may contain one or many lands depends on its area.
I came up with initial design and the relation between the land and the house is many to many:

> ```
> House:
> Id - Name – area –landID – noRooms – hasSwimmingPool
> Land:
> Id – name – area  - location
> Offer: (contain the offer of either a land or a house)
> Id – userID – type – paymentMethod 
> Land_House:
> houseID – landID
> ```

I still cannot relate Land_House table to the offer table.

Is there a better approach than what I did? And what is the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One aproach could be to have a superior Property table, and house and land could have their primary key as a foreign key to this table. This way you could keep the land house relationship with out mixing what a land and a house are on one table, since they are different things, then add the property id on the Offer table, that could be of a house or a land.

It's like thinking of inheritence .

Hope this helps.

Comment: is it similar Land_House table and then I should add the Land_House_id in Offer Table?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, you missed the obvious; your Offer table has no field for Property.  How are you going to store what they made an offer on?  I would suggest putting in a column for OfferType and storing either H (House) or L (Land), and then adding PropertyID.  This way you can join back to the proper ID in either House or Land, depending on the value of OfferType.

Ideally, though, House and Land would be one table with a field for PropertyType.

Comment: sorry, I didn't get your suggestion.